# How can I calculate this fundamental group?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I’m having some troubles with fundamental groups.
How can I calculate the fundamental group of $X = S^2 \cup C$ where $C=\{x^2+y^2=1/4, z\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is the cylinder?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Is $S^2$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $\{ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$?

Comment: The fundamental group is trivial. Any part of your loop that lives on the cylinder can be moved down to the intersection of the cylinder with the sphere. Now use the fact that $\pi_1 (S^2)$ is trivial to construct a homotopy to the constant loop. You might worry that the base-point could live on the cylinder, but this isn't a problem since the space is path-connected. It suffices to compute the fundamental group based at a point on the sphere. As always, the trick is making this rigorous, but it's not so tricky in this case.

Comment: @AymanHourieh you meant $S^2\vee S^2\vee S^1$?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins The fundamental group is in fact $\mathbb Z$; one needs to be careful with informal arguments

Comment: @user8268 You're right!

Comment: @user8268 I would delete my post, except that I think it's a good cautionary tale. What goes wrong with the informal argument?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins It's the "can be moved down" part. There is a non-contractible loop in $X$ which looks somewhat like "D", with the vertical segment being in the cylinder and the arc in the sphere, and it's not possible to move it down.

Comment: I took this exam today and I used @CharlesHudgins ‘s argument… but I failed lol.

Comment: How can I see this group as Z? And why does the argument above fail?

Comment: @user8268 oh my god… you’re right.

Comment: @user8268 Of course. Well there you go. Sorry eallaipigreco. I saw that it was homotopic to $S^2 \land S^2 \land S^2$ (which user8268 helpfully pointed out was also wrong) and was encouraged that my argument was sound. I was only worried about the loop around the cylinder and completely missed the "D" user8268 described.

Answer (score 0):

Contracting the cylinder vertically to a circle, $X$ is homotopy equivalent to the union of a torus and a sphere glued along a circle (the equator of the sphere and a primitive loop on the torus). Now we can use van Kampen:
$$\pi_1(X) \cong (\pi_1(S^1 \times S^1) * \pi_1(S^2))/\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2/\langle1, 0\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}.$$

Alternatively, contracting one of the halves of the sphere gets us to a sphere wedged with a pinched torus. The pinched torus is equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^2$, so $X \simeq S^1 \vee S^2 \vee S^2$ and now a simpler application of van Kampen shows $\pi_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

The generator is given by the other factor of the torus, which before contracting is the "D" shaped loop described in the comments.